# How to use Regex to find string between brackets that must contain a specific character?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a solution to match these

```
#Find.Me Contain at least one dot#...Hey Hey #DontFindMe#
```

I need to find only the `#Find.Me Contain at least one dot#` phrase because it contain a "dot" `.`, the problem my current regex: `\#(.*?)\#` returns both of them: `#Find.Me Contain at least one dot#` and `#DontFindMe#`

**How to change the regex to return only the `#Find.Me Contain at least one dot#`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negated character class:

```
#[^#.]*\.[^#]*#
```

**Explanation**

- `#` Match literally
- `[^#.]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except # or a dot
- `\.` Match a dot
- `[^#]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except #
- `#` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U9n2UI/1)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit tricky, but my thought is you want to check for an even number of '#' ahead too:

```bash
#[^#.]*\.[^#.]*#(?=(?:[^#]*#[^#]*#)*[^#]*$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mIpX8l/1)

---

- `#[^#.]*\.[^#.]*#` - Match exactly as you desire between two literal '#' with exactly a single dot;
- `(?=` - Open a positive lookahead;

  - `(?:[^#]*#[^#]*#)*` - Match a non-capture group 0+ times to match 0+ '#' followed by balanced pairs of '#';
  - `[^#]*$)` - Match 0+ '#' before end-line anchor.

---

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
#(.*?\..*?)#
```

https://regex101.com/r/84dxhG/1

If you want to make sure that `#` are delimiters:

```
#([^#]*\.[^#]*)#
```

https://regex101.com/r/qFpeFR/1

Comment: One problem though this would match `#Find#.Me#`

Comment: true, but OP didn't specifically say anything about that. Added that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you some usefull sites, where you can test different expressions and see live what is slected.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

[Regex](https://regexr.com/)

For accept this as an answer I Am enclosing one of possible solutions:

```
# *([^#]+)
```

Which will select

`#Find.Me Contain at least one dot`#...Hey Hey #DontFindMe#

from sentence

[RegExr solution](https://regexr.com/6vuf7)